# Making a gogocartojs map work in js project

Tags: javascript, html, npm

I created a project and I'm trying to add gogocartoJs in it.
The project works but the map is not showing.

I tried with the guides I found in the site, it looks plain and easy, but there is an step that I'm not understanding (please dont just copy/paste a piece of the site like it was obvious what it is the mistake, because it is not for me)

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://gogocarto.fr/assets/css/gogocarto.min.css"
    />

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gogocarto.fr/js/gogocarto.min.js"></script>

    <title>Hello Webpack</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>Hello Webpack</h1>
      <div id="gogocarto"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        carto = goGoCarto("#gogocarto", {
          data: {
            taxonomy: taxonomy,
            elements: elements
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expect the map to show, and it doesnt

I added the project to github to show better
https://github.com/Aredros/testGogo/tree/master/dist

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Seems like the variables `taxonomy` and `elements` are not defined anywhere. You should show what is on `bundle.js` so we can give you a better answer

Comment: I added a github link to show what is everywhere (except node modules)

Answer (score 0):

[elements](https://pixelhumain.github.io/GoGoCartoJs/docs/dataset-element-configuration.html) & [taxonomy](https://pixelhumain.github.io/GoGoCartoJs/docs/taxonomy-simple.html) are js variables containing data you must provide according to the format described in the documentation.

```json
// taxonomy
let taxonomy = {
    "options":[
    { 
        "id": "eu1",
        "name":"Belgium",
        "color":"#9acd32",
        "icon":"fa-solid fa-building"
    },    
    {
        "id": "eu2",
        "name": "Netherland",
        "color": "#ffa500",
        "icon": "fa-solid fa-fan"
    },
    {
        "id": "eu3",
        "name": "Luxembourg",
        "color": "#a52a2a",
        "icon": "fa-solid fa-money-bill-1"
    }
    ]  
}
```

The only missing info in the documentation is the id key in the taxonomy which must be referenced in your `elements` source dataset.

```json
// elements
let elements = [
    {
        "title": "Brussels",
        "geo": {
        "latitude":50.84,
        "longitude":4.34
        },
        "taxonomy": [ "eu1" ],
    },
    {
        "title": "Namur",
        "geo": {
        "latitude":50.45,
        "longitude":4.88
        },
        "taxonomy": [ "eu1" ],
    },
    {
        "title": "Liege",
        "geo": {
        "latitude":50.62,
        "longitude":5.60
        },
        "taxonomy": [ "eu1" ],
    },
    {
        "title": "Rotterdam",
        "geo": {
        "latitude":51.88,
        "longitude":4.51
        },
        "taxonomy": [ "eu2" ],
    },
    {
        "title": "Amsterdam",
        "geo": {
        "latitude":52.07,
        "longitude":5.12
        },
        "taxonomy": [ "eu2" ],
    },          
]
```

Idealy you should build an API returning `taxonomy classification` & `elements data`. Then perform ajax call in your html page.

```js
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/ajax/url_to_get_elements',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(elements, status) {
        build_map(elements);
      }
    });
    // build map = function with 1 arguments (elements) where you put the call to goGoCarto and options...
```

You can define more than 1 taxonomy group (Example above is about English countries) with the name you want => Cfr. [Advanced Taxonomy](https://pixelhumain.github.io/GoGoCartoJs/docs/taxonomy-advanced.html) with Categories. Your elements can then have multiple taxonomy reference listed `[ "eu1", "week22", 14 ]`. Items in the list can be Integer or String. The only important thing is the ID key and the taxonomy order! Keep the same order in your taxonomy than in your key `"taxonomy":` in your `elements` data sources!

### Point of attention

Because the library is highly configurable with options, colors and icons it is important to put all your <scripts> tags inside <head> tags of your html page!

Comment: forget about direct access to sources via https://gogocarto.fr. Download js & css and refer them in your main js file. <script src="dist/gogocarto.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/gogocarto.css">